# SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected when using a URL in json output

Tags: php, json

I have a problem with when I watch JSON output with PHP containing a URL
My code is as follows:

```
 <?php
   $url = "http://1.2.3.4:8080";
   Header('Content-type: application/json');
 ?>{"status" : "URL" : "<?php echo $url ?>"}
```

My output is then:

```
 {"status" : "URL" : "http://1.2.3.4:8080
 "}
```

And this gives the error message:

> SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected ',' or '}' after property value in
>   object at line 1 column 19 of the JSON data.

Do I change `$url = "http://1.2.3.4:8080";` to `$url = "test";` then it works.

How I can change this so that a URL also work?

Comment: why don't you use json_encode to encode your json properly instead of hard typing it ?

Comment: are you still believe that this **string** with three `:` separated values is a valid JSON? you need `key:value` pairs.

Comment: The code you have shown does not even produce that result. The only way you will get that line break in that position, is if the value of `$url` contained a line break at the end already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let play with the basics instead of re-inventing the wheel:

```
<?php
    $url = "http://1.2.3.4:8080";
    Header('Content-type: application/json');
    $arr = array('status'=>'success', 'url'=>$url);
    echo json_encode($arr, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
?>
```

Output:

```
{"status":"success","url":"http://1.2.3.4:8080"}
```

If you really have a new line somewhere in the string, you could escape it before adding the value into the JSON:

```
$url = str_replace(array("\r\n", "\n", "\r"), "", $url);
```

May the Force be with you.